# How to implement subscription plans in an iPhone application

Tags: ios, ipad, in-app-purchase, auto-renewing

we got a new requirement for creating an iPad application for a web app (business app). In this web app user can subscribe for a month and after that the subscription will be auto renewed. We need to create an iPad app with same features.

I am having some trouble to take a decision for designing the app, here are some points what is in my mind:

- Is it possible to implement monthly subscription plan in an iPad app using iAP, is it okay with the Apple guidelines?
- We can use In-App-Purchase for payment options, so is it possible to implement this auto renewal with iAP? Or just use the web app for payment and auto renewal and use the iPad app as a client app?
- And is there any Apple guidelines against this kind of design?

I know this is not a technical question, but I am new to this iAP. And I found some apple docs also, but I am not sure how it will be in the app as per our design. I am expecting some expert opinions to take a decision regarding this app design. If someone needs more clarification about the question, feel free to ask.

Please share your ideas and experiences.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

With iAP I don't think it is possible to have an auto renewal feature.

According to apple reviews guideline an application shouldn't use a method other than iAP to manage subscriptions

https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html (Look for rules under 11.x) (I don't paste them here as there are under NDA)

Comment: So, what if the renewal process is controlling at server side and just run the iPad app as a client app?

Comment: It would be technically possible, but I can't promise Apple won't refuse this application in regard to section 11 of the review guideline

Answer (score 0):

According to your app you need you want to keep this in AutoRenewable process .Here login with your ituens account and there is an option Manage in App purchases in this fill up the fields accordingly and it will ask an produt id this is very important to you . Hold this with you and you want to add storekit framework for this . And you want to generate an shared secret for this it easy to implement